# Python create tuples using function returning multiple values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of tuples, and I need to add more information to each tuple. The list looks something like this:

```
[(name1, value1), (name2, value2), (name1, value3), ...]
```

I have a function to get the extra information for each tuple, but I need the new tuples to be flat and I can't think of a good way to do that in a list comprehension. I would love to be able to do something like this:

```
new_list = [(name, value, *extra_info(name)) for name, value in old_list]
```

or

```
new_list = [list(name, value, *extra_info(name)) for name, value in old_list]
```

Unfortunately the first one is bad syntax, and the second one doesn't work because `list` only takes in one argument. Is there a way to unpack the tuple returned by `extra_info` in a list comprehension? Failing that, what would be the most Pythonic way to tackle this problem?

To be clear, I want to end up with a list that looks like this:

```
[(name1, value1, extra1, extra2), (name2, value2, extra3, extra4), (name1, value3, extra1, extra2), ...]
```

Comment: `(name, value) + extra_info(name)`?  Assuming `extra_info` returns a tuple?

Comment: @g.d.d.c Yes, `extra_info` returns multiple values, so they get packed into a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to sum lists and convert it to a tuple.

```
new_list = [(name, value) + extra_info(name) for name, value in old_list]
```

Comment: Multiple values get returned as a tuple, and name and value are already in a tuple so I can just add the tuples. This will work perfectly for me!

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
  new_list = [(name, value) + extra_info(name) for name, value in old_list]
```

no need for converting tuples to lists ...

Answer (score 0):

Something I came up with while thinking about this was to use a lambda echo function to pack the new tuples:

```
packer = lambda *x: x
new_list = [packer(name, value, *extra_info(name)) for name, value in old_list]
```